# how to run application on Samsung galaxy tab GT-P1000

Tags: android

I just finished developing an application and i want to run and test it on Samsung Galaxy Tab GT-P1000. 
i followed the steps on this link. http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/device.html

and I turned on USB debugging and the icon on top says the device is connected through USB. In   Eclipse on Windows 7, I don't see the Galaxy Tab in my list. when i tried to see it through run configuration, i can see only my virtual device.

I think i have to install USB drive from this link.
http://www.samsung.com/us/support/downloads/GT-P1000

but i am not sure which sub category to select.

can somebody please please help me...

Comment: Hi did your application worked for debugging? can you please explain what all are the steps. aM FACIONG THE SAME ISSUE

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have the Kies application, it also contains the drivers. Windows 7 should be able to find the drivers itself if Kies doesn't solve your problem.

http://www.samsung.com/au/smartphone/galaxys/Kies_2.0.0.11014_49_2.exe